# Is there any way how can I make one row hypertext in vertical menu?

Tags: html, css

I am setting up a new web page and making a horizontal menu. The hypertext is made by 2 words. It should be in one row, but actually one word = 1 row. I have here in CSS a hover effect over it, whenever the hover effect works, the hypertext is in this moment in one row. I am a little bit lost and confused. I don't know what to change, can you help me?

I have already tried changing in CSS `display` attribute to `table, block, solid`. Also I have tried `min-width`, with hopes that text will expand on one line, but it didn't helped at all. Also I tried to change margin and padding but nothing changed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgqOJ.jpg

HTML

```
<div id ="panel">
 <img src= "Logo.jpg" alt="Logo">
 <h3>Nabidka</h3>
 <ul>
 <br />
 <br />
 <br />
 <li><a href ="index.html">Hlavní stránka</a></li>
 <li><a href ="program.html">Program 2020</a></li>
 <li><a href ="where_we_are.html">Kde sídlíme</a></li>
 <li><a href ="organisators.html">Organizátoři</a></li>
 <li><a href ="about_us.html">O nás</a></li>                                                    
 <li><a href ="gallery.html">Galerie</a></li>
 <li class ="last"><a href = "facebook.html">Facebook</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#panel{
width: 15%;
float: left;  
background: rgb(153,153,153);
padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#panel h3{
display: none;
}

#panel ul{
margin: 0;                              
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
background: rgb(153,153,153);
}

#panel li{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
/*border-top: 0px solid rgb(0,176,176);*/
/*border-width: 2px 0px 0px 0px;*/ /*line between hypertexts*/
/*margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;*/                           
/*margin-bottom: 1px;*/
display: block; 
} 

#panel a{
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
color: black;
font-size: 120%;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 6px 185px 6px 4px; 
margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px; 
background: rgb(153,153,153);
}

#panel a:hover{           /*redrawing*/
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
background: rgb(0,0,0);
padding: 4px 0px 4px 2px;
min-width: 100%;
}

#panel li.spodni{
height: 1500px;
}

img {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `white-space`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the width in your `a` tag selector in CSS was limiting the width of the elements forcing a text wrap. this fixes it

```
<div id ="panel">
    <img src= "Logo.jpg" alt="Logo">
    <h3>Nabidka</h3>
    <ul>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <li><a href ="index.html">Hlavní stránka</a></li>
    <li><a href ="program.html">Program 2020</a></li>
    <li><a href ="where_we_are.html">Kde sídlíme</a></li>
    <li><a href ="organisators.html">Organizátoři</a></li>
    <li><a href ="about_us.html">O nás</a></li>                                                    
    <li><a href ="gallery.html">Galerie</a></li>
    <li class ="last"><a href = "facebook.html">Facebook</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<style>
#panel{
width: 15%;
float: left;  
background: rgb(153,153,153);
padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#panel h3{
display: none;
}

#panel ul{
margin: 0;                              
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
background: rgb(153,153,153);
}

#panel li{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
/*border-top: 0px solid rgb(0,176,176);*/
/*border-width: 2px 0px 0px 0px;*/ /*line between hypertexts*/
/*margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;*/                           
/*margin-bottom: 1px;*/
display: block; 
} 

#panel a{
display: block;
width: 150px;
height: 30px;
color: black;
font-size: 120%;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 6px 185px 6px 4px; 
margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px; 
background: rgb(153,153,153);
}

#panel a:hover{           /*redrawing*/
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
background: rgb(0,0,0);
padding: 4px 0px 4px 2px;
min-width: 100%;
}

#panel li.spodni{
height: 1500px;
}

img {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: anytime @MikeFreestyler

Answer (score 1):

The a tag width has been limited in normal state:

```
#panel a{
display: block;
width: 100px; --> this line
height: 30px;
color: black;
font-size: 120%;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 6px 185px 6px 4px; 
margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px; 
background: rgb(153,153,153);
}
```

You could remove the line **width: 100px;** because **display:block** will set the element width to 100% of its container.